# Is there a way to highlight a button option displayed through Choice using PromptOptions in MS Chat BOT created in C# and SDKV4?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I am creating a chatBot using microsoft Bot framework using SDKV4 in C#. The BOT has multiple waterfall dialogs.

In this one dialog class shows few choice options in form of buttons using Prompt Options.I want to know whether or is there a way to highlight one(only one) of the buttons displayed in different color.

If we observe, in general the choice buttons are displayed in White(background of button) and Blue(blue text and border of button) combination.

So is there a way to change the white background color? Either only color or making the button to give blinking effect or flashing effect based on a certain conditions.

Let's say there is a bool flag ,if it is true i want to display one of the option in other color or as is if it is false.

Code:

```
 return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                        "choicePrompt",
                        new PromptOptions
                        {
                            Prompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply("Please click/choose any one from the following: "),
                            Choices = new[] { new Choice { Value = "Option0" }, new Choice { Value = "Option1" }, new Choice { Value = "Option2" }, new Choice { Value = "Option3" }, new Choice { Value = "Option4" }, new Choice { Value = "Option5" }}.ToList(),
                            RetryPrompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply("Sorry, I did not understand that. Please choose any one from the options displayed below: "),
                        });
```

I want the **Option2** to be displayed in different color based on Bool flag as tried to explain above.

Is this possible? or this is a wrong expectation and it cannot be done?

if it is possible can anyone please provide me the detailed steps to achieve this. Please note that i am a bit new to coding hence i would humbly request to provide detailed steps if this is behaviour is achievable.

Thanks in Advance

Regards

ChaitanyaNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this, no. The closest thing that [PromptOptions](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Prompts/PromptOptions.cs) offers is the `Style` property, but even that is only for setting different [ListStyles](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Choices/ListStyle.cs), none of which offer any color customization.

If you're only using Web Chat, there's likely some CSS customization I can help you with. But if you're using any other channel, you're pretty much stuck with how the channel decides to render the choices.

Alternatively, instead of choices, you could send small Adaptive Cards and set a different [background image](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/) for the first one. Note, however, that the channel doesn't have to display the background image (although it likely will). Non-Microsoft channels (Slack, Facebook, etc) also [don't work very well with using Adaptive Cards as inputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channels-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#card-support-by-channel).

---

To answer further comments, I was able to find the appropriate CSS selector for Choices. This may differ in your version of Web Chat, but I used:

```css
.css-1wegtiu > ul > li:first-child > .css-y5o52s > button {
    background: red
}
```

and this resulted in:

[image]

Comment: @mdrichardsom  = I am using a Web Chat Channel. Can you please help me with CSS that you were trying to explain? Coming to the adaptive card, i think Adaptive card is not suitable in my case because i am displaying the buttons based upon some conditions like if the logged in user of specific type i display only few options if not i display all options. From there based on selected option the activity happens. So could you please help me out with CSS thing?

Comment: @ChaitanyaNG I'll start working on the CSS, but it's a low-priority issue for me since it's 1) just out of our scope of work, and 2) it's not *easy* and will take a decent amount of troubleshooting.

Comment: No Problem, take your time. Please let me know your inputs on how to achieve this when you have time. Thanks for the explanation till now and for your time.

Comment: @ChaitanyaNG I've updated my answer with the CSS selector I used. You can change colors, etc as you wish via CSS. For anything more advanced, like conditions, you'll likely need to use some JavaScript.

Comment: Please give me some more time for me to work on the solution you have provided. i'll up vote it later. For now i have accepted your answer. But, thanks for all your time and support till now.

Comment: @ChaitanyaNG Will do. Just be sure to @.mention me if needed to make sure I get notified.